# Not returning true when value matches

Tags: arrays, node.js, for-loop, if-statement

So i've this function. InscripcionesDB is a list of classesID, and claseDB is just a classID

```
async function verificarInscripcion(claseId, username) {

   var inscripcionesDB = await obtenerInscripciones(username);
   var claseDB = await Clase.findOne({ _id: claseId })


   for (let i = 0; i < inscripcionesDB.length; i++) {

       if (inscripcionesDB[i]._id == claseDB._id) {


           console.log(true);

       }

       console.log(false);

       console.log(inscripcionesDB[i]._id, 'CLASSESID');
       console.log(clasedb._id, 'CLASSID');

   }

}
```

So the problem is, there is one elementId which is matching, but the output is always false.. What Im doing wrong? This are the outputs:

```
5d959aa70d3ee404889d2b26 CLASSESID
5d82e4dc5770f32b50246657 CLASSID
false
5d959abc0d3ee404889d2b28 CLASSESID
5d82e4dc5770f32b50246657 CLASSID
false
5d82e4dc5770f32b50246657 CLASSESID // THIS ONE IS MATCHING
5d82e4dc5770f32b50246657 CLASSID //
false
```

Comment: `clasedb !== claseDB` I don't know what the former is, but it's what you log. You are checking the latter.

Comment: Not sure but can you try converting your both Id's to strings before comparing, something like ```if (inscripcionesDB[i]._id.toString() == claseDB._id.toString())```

Comment: Why do you `findOne` by id just to get the id of the found object? You allready have the id in `claseId`. You'd also simply call find on `inscripcionesDB`

Comment: .toString() Worked perfectly. Why does this worked with .tostring and not without it?

Comment: Like @MohammedAmirAnsari said, in mongoose there's a virtual get that is ```.id```, so try to do this: ```inscripcionesDB[i].id == claseDB.id``` the id is casted to string and not an object

Comment: @NicoAybar It's because ```_id``` is an object, so you're comparing objects and not strings like ```.id.toString()``` or just ```id```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are console logging this : `console.log(clasedb._id, 'CLASSID');` but you are comparing this: `inscripcionesDB[i]._id == claseDB._id` Try comparing `inscripcionesDB[i]._id == clasedb._id`, but also try console logging out what is `claseDB` as I think that's what you're really interested in comparing. You might also want to have your `console.log('false')` in an else block because as it is, it will always log false.